# Problem implementing SSL/TLS Certificate Verify Message

Tags: javascript, ssl, certificate, verification

I am trying to implement `Certificate Verify` based on the RFC
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5246#section-7.4.8

it states specifically, that I need to concatenate all the handshake messages prior to this moment then it should be hashed and signed by private key.

I am looking at SSL communication in the packet capture and peforming

```
const crypto = require('crypto')
const fs = require('fs')

let clientKey = fs.readFileSync(`endpointKey.pem`)

let raw = 'hexdump of all handshake_messages prior to this point'
let rawBuffer = Buffer.from(raw.match(/.{2}/g).map(value => {return parseInt(value, 16)})))

console.log(crypto.sign('RSA-SHA256', rawBuffer, clientKey))
```

and the result is different from what was calculated on the endpoint device (I am using the same private and public keys as endpoint).

Please advise, appreciate the help in advance.

Comment: A few thoughts for you: make sure your input to the hash is the same. All the client and server handshake messages (except for the one including the certificate verify request) need to be dumped verbatim, including the type and length (but nothing from the record layer); why not use ```Buffer.from( raw, "hex" )``` if it supported, or better still make raw a Buffer anyway, so you don't need to convert at all; the supported_signature_algorithms field of the CertificateRequest message may contain multiple values, you'll need to sequentially hash and compare to get a match.

Comment: Buffoonism, thank you very much, you were correct (about everything),
I needed to read only the structure of handshake_messages.
It works now. Really appreciate you reading RFC for me one more time (I read it like 10 times before).

Comment: My pleasure! RFCs are written by committee, so their structure and choice of language is always a bit odd. ;)

Comment: "RFCs are written by committee" The authors are always individuals, never organizations. They are discussed and worked on, typically but not always, in a working group. Yet, authors remain individuals.